# Autocomplete functionality for textarea in angular 4

Tags: angular, mention

I am working on chatting application. so here I am doing `@` functionality for text area means, while clicking `@` button or writing `@` one autocomplete list should open. That will contain username for a tag. I have got an idea in jQuery but I want to do in Angular.

So far I am not able to do like this in Angular; if anybody has an idea, please share with me.

Comment: This `@` functionality is called **Mentions**. Try looking into [`angular-mentions`](https://github.com/dmacfarlane/angular-mentions)

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey could you please tell me how to populate mention- items dynamic .

Answer (score 0):

You can try angular text input autocomplete

Please refer the following [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-text-input-autocomplete)